# Highlight effect while pressing item in custom ListView adapter

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

There's a system visual effect everytime you click a view in Android. In Lollipop it's the ripple effect. When I created a ListView and associated it to an ordinary ArrayAdapter, this effect was present. Now that I've added a custom ListView, this effect is lost.

Now, I've tried to isolate what the problem is, and since using the same list item layout with a default adapter worked nicely, I would say that the problem is on my custom adapter.

I've seen many solutions related to this case that just implemented the ripple effect calling some drawables; this is not what I'm trying to do. The ripple effect shows only because I'm running the app on Android 5, now what I want to do is to have the default system highlight effect for my items when they're being clicked.

Here are the (hopefully) related pieces of my custom adapter:

```
public class CustomCardSetsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Card> totalList;
    ArrayList<Boolean> hiddenItems;
    ListView parentLV;
    Integer curPosition = -1;

    public static int selectedRowIndex;

    public CustomCardSetsAdapter(CardSets cardList, ListView parentListView)
    {
        this.parentLV = parentListView;
        assignSetValues(cardList);

        totalList =      cardList.getBlackrockMountain();
        totalList.addAll(cardList.getClassic());
        totalList.addAll(cardList.getCurseofNaxxramas());
        totalList.addAll(cardList.getGoblinsvsGnomes());

        Collections.sort(totalList,
                new Comparator<Card>() {
                    public int compare(Card f1, Card f2) {
                        return f1.toString().compareTo(f2.toString());
                    }
                });

        hiddenItems = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalList.size(); i++) {
            if(!totalList.get(i).getCollectible())
                hiddenItems.add(true);
            else
                hiddenItems.add(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (totalList.size() - getHiddenCount());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final int index = getRealPosition(position);

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_list_item, parentLV, false);
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer prevPosition = curPosition;
                curPosition = position;

                if(prevPosition >= parentLV.getFirstVisiblePosition() &&
                        prevPosition <= parentLV.getLastVisiblePosition())
                {
                    View view = parentLV.getChildAt(prevPosition- parentLV.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                    parentLV.getAdapter().getView(prevPosition,view, parentLV);
                }

                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });


        Card curCard = totalList.get(index);

        TextView cardName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardName);
        cardName.setText(curCard.getName());
        setRarityColor(curCard,cardName);

        TextView manaCost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manaCost);
        manaCost.setText((curCard.getCost()).toString());

        ImageView setIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.setIcon);
        setSetIcon(curCard,setIcon);

        if(position == curPosition)
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        else
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return R.layout.card_list_item;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    private int getHiddenCount()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i <totalList.size();i++)
            if(hiddenItems.get(i))
                count++;
        return count;
    }

    private int getRealPosition(int position) {
        int hElements = getHiddenCountUpTo(position);
        int diff = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<hElements;i++) {
            diff++;
            if(hiddenItems.get(position+diff))
                i--;
        }
        return (position + diff);
    }

    private int getHiddenCountUpTo(int location) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<=location;i++) {
            if(hiddenItems.get(i))
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're setting the list item background color to white. What color is the ripple?

Comment: By default it's grey + a darker grey. Anyway without changing the cells background the effect is still missing.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `View.OnClickListener` and handling this through `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`?

Comment: Whoa, I put a placeholder OnItemClickListener (a simple Toast) and now the cell is getting the effect. I'll look more into it when I get home. Meanwhile... do you know why this worked?

Comment: ListView does its own touch handling. If you set a click listener on the row itself, ListView assumes you're doing your own touch handling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in your ListView XML, add:

```
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
```

I also think you are using your adapter wrong...

Use the ViewHolder Pattern on your Adapter:

```
public class CustomCardSetsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<Card> totalList;
    ArrayList<Boolean> hiddenItems;
    ListView parentLV;
    Integer curPosition = -1;
    public static int selectedRowIndex;

    private class ViewHolderRow{
        TextView cardName;
        TextView manaCost;
        ImageView setIcon;
    }



   public CustomCardSetsAdapter(CardSets cardList, ListView parentListView)
   {
       this.parentLV = parentListView;
       assignSetValues(cardList);

       totalList =      cardList.getBlackrockMountain();
       totalList.addAll(cardList.getClassic());
       totalList.addAll(cardList.getCurseofNaxxramas());
       totalList.addAll(cardList.getGoblinsvsGnomes());

       Collections.sort(totalList,
            new Comparator<Card>() {
                public int compare(Card f1, Card f2) {
                    return f1.toString().compareTo(f2.toString());
                }
            });

       hiddenItems = new ArrayList<>();

       for (int i = 0; i < totalList.size(); i++) {
           if(!totalList.get(i).getCollectible())
               hiddenItems.add(true);
           else
               hiddenItems.add(false);
       }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (totalList.size() - getHiddenCount());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final int index = getRealPosition(position);
         ViewHolderRow theRow;
        if(convertView == null) {
           theRow = new ViewHolderRow();
           LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_list_item, parentLV, false);

            // Cache your views
            theRow.cardName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cardName);
            theRow.manaCost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.manaCost);
            theRow.setIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.setIcon);

            // Set the Tag to the ViewHolderRow
            convertView.setTag(theRow);
        }else{
           // get the Row to re-use
           theRow = (ViewHolderRow) convertView.getTag();
        }

    //... Removed convertView.setOnClickListener  

    Card curCard = totalList.get(index);

    // Set Items
    theRow.cardName.setText(curCard.getName());
    setRarityColor(curCard,theRow.cardName);
    theRow.manaCost.setText((curCard.getCost()).toString());
    setSetIcon(curCard,theRow.setIcon);

       if(position == curPosition){
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
       }else{
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
       }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return R.layout.card_list_item;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    private int getHiddenCount()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i <totalList.size();i++)
            if(hiddenItems.get(i))
                count++;
         return count;
    }

    private int getRealPosition(int position) {
        int hElements = getHiddenCountUpTo(position);
        int diff = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<hElements;i++) {
            diff++;
            if(hiddenItems.get(position+diff))
                i--;
        }
        return (position + diff);
    }

    private int getHiddenCountUpTo(int location) {
       int count = 0;
       for(int i=0;i<=location;i++) {
             if(hiddenItems.get(i))
                count++;
             }
           return count;
     }
}
```

Set an onListItemClickListener instead of using this on the entire convertView...

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(ListListener);


private final OnItemClickListener ListListener = new OnItemClickListener{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3)     {
          // ... Do something on click       
    }
}
```